What are the 3 categories of things that Yisro heard?
B"H
In the beginning of Parsha Yisro, it says:


Now Moses' father in law, Jethro, the chieftain of Midian, heard all that God had done for Moses and for Israel, His people that the
Lord had taken Israel out of Egypt.       א. וַיִּשְׁמַ֞ע יִתְר֨וֹ כֹהֵ֤ן
מִדְיָן֙ חֹתֵ֣ן משֶׁ֔ה אֵת֩ כָּל־אֲשֶׁ֨ר עָשָׂ֤ה אֱלֹהִים֙ לְמשֶׁ֔ה
וּלְיִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל עַמּ֑וֹ כִּֽי־הוֹצִ֧יא יְהוָֹ֛ה


אֶת־יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל מִמִּצְרָֽיִם:
That Yisro heard everything Hashem did for Yisroel, that he took them out of Egypt.
Seemingly, the idea of "all he did for Yisroel", IS that he took them out of Egypt!
But the fact that it says two separate things, "all the He did for Yisroel", AND "He took them out of Egypt", implies that they are two different things.
On top of this, Rashi explains the beginning words of "and yisro heard", as referring to something else:

Now…Jethro…heard: What news did he hear that [made such an impression
that] he came? The splitting of the Red Sea and the war with Amalek. —
[from Zev. 116a, and Mechilta, combining the views of Rabbi Joshua and
Rabbi Eliezer]     וַיִּשְׁמַע יִתְרוֹ: מַה שְּׁמוּעָה שָׁמַע וּבָא?
קְרִיעַת יַם סוּף וּמִלְחֶמֶת עֲמָלֵק:

That just the words and yisro heard", alone, without any other part of the verse (since that's what Rashi references), imply that he heard about the war of amalek, and the splitting of the sea, neither of which referring  to the fact that "He took us out of Egypt".
So there are three categories of things here:

All that Hashem did for Yisroel

That He took them out of Egypt

And yisro heard-- war of amalek and splitting of the sea


What's the idea behind these ideas, and what's the first idea?

I think when rashi says וישמע יתרו it’s implicit he’s referring to the כל אשר עשה

@CuriousYid then he should have said גו, but he didn't.

I just looked at all the rashi on the pasuk. It seems on וישמע יתרו he says that refers to Yam Suf and Amalek, and then by את כל אשר עשה it refers to the Manna, the Well, and Amalek, and then he says the הוציא was the greatest of all. So your question about “what’s כל אשר עשה״ is answered by Rashi himself. I think a better question is why split up each of these events amongst וישמע and כל אשר, and on top of that why is Amalek mentioned for both
